# Rasberry Pi 3B+, PiCamera 1.3, Camera not detected

Tags: pi-3, raspicam

I have attached the ribbon cable from the Raspberry Pi CSI port to the Camera, and have ensured the connections are not loose.
I use the `vcgencmd` `get_camera` command and it returns:

```
supported=1 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

i2c and Legacy Camera enabled in the Raspberry Pi configuration Interfaces options

Comment: is the cable oriented correctly?

Comment: I think it is, I have it the same way it's displayed on the RaspberryPi website
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera/2

Comment: I have fixed the issue now, I think the problem was that my ribbon cable was not working